# trouble combining two numeric columns into one R

Tags: r, dataframe

so I am having a bit of bother combining two columns into one. I have two columns of ages, which are split into child and adolescent columns. For example:

```
child adolescent
1   NA  12
2   NA  15
3   NA  12
4   NA  12
5   NA  13
6   NA  13
7   NA  13
8   NA  14
9   14  15
10  NA  12
11  12  13
12  NA  12
13  NA  13
14  NA  14
15  NA  14
16  12  13
17  NA  14
18  NA  13
19  NA  13
20  NA  14
21  NA  12
22  NA  13
23  12  15
24  NA  13
25  NA  15
26  NA  12
27  NA  15
28  NA  15
29  NA  13
30  NA  12
31  13  15`
```

Now what I would like to do is combine them into one column called "age" and remove all the na values. However when I try the following code, I encounter a problem:

```
age<- c(na.omit(data$child),na.omit(data$adolescent))
```

The problem being that my original data has 514 rows, yet when I combine the two columns, removing the nas, I somehow end up with 543 values, not 514 and I don't know why.

So, if possible, could someone explain firstly why I am getting more values than I planned, and secondly what might be a better way to combine the two columns.

EDIT: I am looking for something like this

```
   age
1   12
2   15
3   12
4   12
5   13
6   13
7   13
8   14
9   14
10  12
11  12
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  14
16  12
17  14
18  13
19  13
20  14
21  12
22  13
23  12
24  13
25  15
26  12
27  15
28  15
29  13
30  12
31  13
32  14
33  13
34  11
35  15
36  13
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please define what you mean by "combine"?

Comment: @BondedDust my apologies, I will amend my question for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
age<- c(na.omit(data$child),na.omit(data$adolescent))
```

concatenates all the non-missing values from the `child` field to all the non-missing values from the `adolescent` field.   I suspect you want to use one of these solutions

```
# youngest age
age<- pmin(data$child,data$adolescent,na.rm=T)

# oldest age
age<- pmax(data$child,data$adolescent,na.rm=T)

# child age, replaced with adolescent if missing
age<- data$child
age[is.na(age)] <- data$adolescent[is.na(age)]
#       ^   notice same logical index   ^
#       |_______________________________|
```

Comment: That last one worked perfectly and was exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your code works on the example data, but you could try this:

```
age <- c(data$child, data$adolescent)
age <- age[!is.na(age)]
```

This combines the two columns from the data frame into a vector and removes all `NA` elements.

Comment: That didn't do the trick but thanks for your input nonetheless!

Answer (score 2):

```
df$age <-  ifelse( !(is.na(df$child)), df$child , df$adolescent)
```

Comment: Do you want column age to be in the same data.frame?